# Execute shell command on windows

Tags: shell, cygwin, sh

Helo guys , lately i faced a problem when executing a .sh file on windows

```
0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60EA0000, RegionSize 0x40000, State 0x10000
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
```

any idea what's wrong , until recently i was able to execute the command normally

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you by any chance using *32bit* *Cygwin* version (check it by running `uname -m` in the *shell*)? Download and install the *64bit* one (*setup\_64*), and switch to it.

Comment: that command only works when i removed C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe from path env , the command gives me 64 bit

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention to the path. Are you running the command from *Cygwin*? If yes, why are you mixing environments? If no, why the tag? *Cygwin* has its own shell, so does *MinGW*. Keep them separate.